# Why my jquery multiselect plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I´m developing a school project using jquery multiselect plugin but the plugin isn't working fine.
Thats my code where i create the multiselect menu.

```
@using nsaprojeto.Controllers
@model dadosPassar

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Filtros1";
}
<html>  
<center>
<h1> Zona / Ap </h1>
</center>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Filtros", "L_AccessPoint", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Label("Aps:")
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.zoneap_id, Model.zoneap, new{ @class = "listbox"})
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value ="Submit" />
    }
           </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">

        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $(".listbox").multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true

                });
            });
    </script>

    @if(ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("@ViewBag.Message")
        </script>
    }



</body>
</html>
```

And that is how i place values in the selectItem

```
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ddd", Value = "1" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "aaa", Value = "2" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "bbb", Value = "3" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ccc", Value = "4" });
```

And thats is the output displayed,

[image: 1]

Dont appears the SelectAllOption, why is that appening??

I see so many tutorials and all of then show something like that, with the checkbox option and mine dont have that.

I'm doing something wrong??

**Edit**

Thats the controller code with the get and post method

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Filtros1()
        {
            var model = new dadosPassar();

            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ddd", Value = "1" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "aaa", Value = "2" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "bbb", Value = "3" });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ccc", Value = "4" });

            model.zoneap = list;

            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Filtros1(dadosPassar teste)
        {
            teste.zoneap = BindList();
            if (teste.zoneap_id != null)
            {
                List<SelectListItem> selectedteditems = teste.zoneap.Where(p => teste.zoneap_id.Contains(int.Parse(p.Value))).ToList();

                ViewBag.Message = "Selected Countries";
                foreach (var select in selectedteditems)
                {
                    select.Selected = true;
                    ViewBag.Message += select.Text + ", ";

                }
            }

            return View(teste);
        }
```

Now, after some changes that's what is displayed, but when i click in the non selected box that dont open the box with the options.

This is what shows in view-source code, so the values are correct
[image: 2]

But when i click in the box nothing happens.

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Thats is what is showing in the console log

[image: 5]

**Conclusion:**

I has using the default asp.net _layout that have some calls/invokes to js files that entered in conflit with my my later invocations.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Can you share link for any one you tried

Comment: The last one i tried was that video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nreT5R16y3I&t=739s

Comment: @Rush.2707 You could fin anything?

Comment: Are you able to share the rendered html for the @Html.ListBoxFor? I've just created a quick html file with the scripts and css links you have provided and works as expected

Comment: @AlexGrogan I edit my question and add what you ask

Comment: Have you now changed your html as it seems like the .multiselect function is now working? It just isn't rendering your options

Comment: Going back to your original question (before you made an edit), you need to show us whats showing in the console logs as it seems like there's a script error. 
My guess is that if you created a new MVC project, the jquery file would also be imported in the _layout.cshtml which will conflict with the one your importing at the top of this file

Comment: @AlexGrogan now the box looks like the box of the video, but when i click in the box that dont expand with the options.

Comment: @AlexGrogan I edit the question with the console log output

Comment: It seems like you fixed the multiselect box (which is why it looks like the one in the video), but it's just not loading your options. Have you got a get method which is setting the options?

Comment: @AlexGrogan I implement what you said and the values are going to the select, but the button none selected dont expand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243901/discussion-between-alex-grogan-and-alexandre-lourenco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just used the same links that you have provided and created a quick multi select. Everything ran as expected (you can click on "Run code snippet")

Few things you should check

1. Check to see if there's any errors in the console log (you can view this in your browsers DevTools)
2. Make sure the class is being set correctly on your @Html.ListBoxFor
3. Make sure the multiselect function is running after the select element has be rendered

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<select id="example-getting-started" class="listbox" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.listbox').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

****EDIT****

Make sure you have a get method in your controller for the page

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Filtros1(){
    var model = new dadosPassar();

    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ddd", Value = "1" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "aaa", Value = "2" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "bbb", Value = "3" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ccc", Value = "4" });

    model.zoneap = list;

    return View(model)

}
```

Comment: @AlexandreLourenço I've just edited my answer with an example get method you need in your controller which will work with your original cshtml file